# Form response: 'Unable to handle request HTTP ERROR 500'. What have I done wrong?

Tags: php, forms

I have tried to code a php form on website but get error 500. I can't work out what I have done wrong. Can you look through the code to see what I have done wrong.
PHP:

```
<?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$name = $email = $phone = $enquiry = "";

if ( $_SERVER[ "REQUEST_METHOD" ] == "POST" ) {

  if ( empty( $_POST[ "name" ] ) ) {
    $nameErr = "Name is required";
  } else {
    $name = test_input( $_POST[ "name" ] );
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if ( !preg_match( "/^[a-zA-Z-' ]*$/", $name ) ) {
      $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
    }
  }
  if ( empty( $_POST[ "email" ] ) ) {
    $emailErr = "Email is required";
  } else {
    $email = test_input( $_POST[ "email" ] );
    // check if e-mail address is well-formed
    if ( !filter_var( $email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL ) ) {
      $emailErr = "Invalid email format";
    }
  }

  if ( empty( $_POST[ "phone" ] ) ) {
    $comment = "";
  } else {
    $comment = test_input( $_POST[ "phone" ] );
  }

  if ( empty( $_POST[ "enquiry" ] ) ) {
    $comment = "";
  } else {
    $comment = test_input( $_POST[ "enquiry" ] );
  }

}


// Create the email and send the message
$destination = "jenny@sydneylactation.com.au"; 
$subject = "Website Contact Form Enquiry:  $name";
$body = "You have received a new message from your website contact form.\\n\\n"."Here are the details:\\n\\nName: $name\\n\\nEmail: $email\\n\\nPhone: $phone\\n\\nEnquiry:\\n$enquiry";

$header = "From: noreply@sydneylactation.com.au\\n"; 
$headers   = array();
$headers[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
$headers[] = "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1";
$headers[] = "From: " . $fromAddress;
$headers[] = "Subject: " . $subject;
$headers[] = "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion();

mail($destination, $subject, $message, implode("\r\n", 
$headers));

// mail($to,$subject,$msg,$headers);
echo "Email successfully sent.";

?>
```

HTML FORM:

```
 <form id="contact-form" method="post" action="/contact.php" role="form">
          <div class="messages"></div>
          <div class="controls">
               <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-10">
                   <div class="form-group">
                  <input id="form_name" type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name*" required="required" data-error="Your name is required." >
                  <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
                 </div>
              <div class="col-md-10">
                   <div class="form-group">
                  <input id="form_email" type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email*" required="required" data-error="Valid email is required." >
                  <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
                 </div>
              <div class="col-md-10">
                   <div class="form-group">
                  <input id="form_phone" type="text" name="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone" >
                  <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
                 </div>
            </div>
               <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-10">
                   <div class="form-group">
                  <textarea id="form_enquiry" name="enquiry" class="form-control" placeholder="Enquiry*" rows="6" required="required"  data-error="Please, leave us a message."></textarea>
                  <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
                 </div>
              <div class="col-md-12">
                   <input class="btn btn-large btn-primary centre mt-10" type="submit" value="Submit" >

                 </div>
            </div>
               
             </div>
        </form>
```

I have followed instructions from others to make form work but changes made still end up with error.
It is a simple form but I seem to have a lack of understanding of what I am doing wrong.
Please help me.

Comment: First, turn on php error reporting then we can see the specific error instead of a generic one. Then we might be able to help you - or you might even be able to fix it yourself

Comment: `\\n` after the email address does not seem correct - typically that would be `\r\n` for a linebreak. Where is `$fromAddress` defined? The `$header` variable is never used and the whole logic seems a little off - if the user fails to enter a name or email address processing continues as the errors are ignored

Comment: Where is `$message` defined? Do you mean `$body`?

Comment: If the `contact.php` form processor were to work correctly it would essentially be a blank page with a little message and no way back to the actual content nor any branding. Normal practise would be to use a redirect after successful processing back to a styled page perhaps with thank you message &/or error messages. As your index page is `.html` rather than `.php` you limit what post-processing you do after you submit the email/contact form

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius To be sure, it's better to use the constant `PHP_EOL`

Comment: @shaedrich - yes indeed, that tends to be what I use in cases like this

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the line where you send the mail, is that a hard line ending, pushing $headers onto a new line? That will call a 500 error.

Take a look at /var/log/apache2/error.log (if you're on Debian) or /var/log/httpd/error.log (if on RHEL or similar).

There are a number of issues with your code, but first focus on the happy path, and get the thing working.